# Google Analytics : How to track traffic from blog to homepage within same domain?

Tags: google-analytics

My homepage is :
`http://example.com/`

My blog is :
`http://example.com/blog/`

What I want to know is how many users went from `/blog/` to `/` (i.e., blog to homepage).

And it could be not only `/blog/` but from `/blog/article01/` to homepage, etc... In other words, all blog traffic to the homepage.

I see many options within Google Analytics but none of them seemed to allow me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Behavior -> Site content -> Content drilldown. Then select as secondary dimension "Destination Page".

Apply filters to first and secondary dimensions as you prefer. In that case:

- Include -> Level 1 page -> containing -> /blog/
- Include -> Destination Page -> exact match -> /

If you want, you can also create an Advanced Segment for people who visit your blog pages. So you can distinguish them even from other visitors.

You can even use Content Grouping to distinguish content on your website and then use that for example in Visitors Flow and see in much more detail how people behave.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Just one thing. Are you sure this covers the views from `/blog/article01/` to `/` as well? Because I only get `/blog/` in the `Page path level 1` (Same with `containing` or even `begin with`)

Comment: "Page path level 1" means "everything in 1st subfolder". Try to click on /blog/ and you'll se its children.

Comment: Ok so after applying the filters you said, if there is "no data for this view", it basically means nobody (even me when I was testing) has be counted as going from blog to homepage?

Comment: Yes, but double check your filters, and as secondary dimension that you didn't select the wrong destination page (there are multiple ones). Also check on Behavior Flow report, and highlight only traffic through /blog/ and see if it's coming also from the homepage.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: I am sorry to say that no : ( At the time of the question I could not say if it worked because I wasn't sure there even were any user jumping on the HP from the blog. However since that time, in many occasions I myself did jump (blog -> HP) using various devices, and the result is thill the same : "There is no data for this view"... Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe is that because typical blog article URL being /blog/article01/, there no such thing as /blog/article01/ in "page path level 1" column (only /blog/)

Comment: Can you check your homepage in other reports? Can you see it showing as " / "? Check your implementation using Real Time Reporting. Add at the bottom of a blog post url `?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test`. Then in Real Time reporting go to Traffic Source. Click on "test" and you can follow yourself navigating in the website.

Comment: Yes "/" appears and I see myself in the real time reporting as you said.

Comment: Note that my website.com/ redirects to website.com/homepage/index.html. So I try to set : destination page = /homepage/index.html as the only filter in content drilldown, but the only "Page path level 1" in the table is /homepage/. And if I put destination page = /homepage/ instead, then there's no "page path level 1"

Comment: The only way I could get "some" results was : Site content > All Pages > Primary dimention : landing page, secondary dimention : destination page. Filter : include landing page that contains /blog/ and exclude destination page that contains /blog/.

With these settings, I get some results, but I am not sure to be getting the results I want to track... (only landing pages?...)

Comment: If your homepage gets redirected, that last would be your homepage in GA. So you should look for /homepage/index.html as destination page

Comment: which as stated above I did, with no luck unfortunately ; (

Comment: Check for your homepage in other reports like Content Drilldown and All Pages. Find here your homepage.